# filtering result using eager loading

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am creating a search in laravel for an API but my search gives me the wrong results. I am trying to search by location and food type. I have the following tables:

1. foods
2. shops
3. shop_food
4. users
5. comments

Here is my search code:

```
 public function searchShop($food, $location)
{
    //
    if($food == " " || $location == " "){
        return $this->index();
    }

    //get all records where city and food are equal to
    $shops = Shop::where('city', '=', $location)
        ->with('comments.user')
        ->with(['foods'=> function($query) use($food){
                $query->where('name','=', 'fish pepper'); }])
        ->get();

        //check if empty and return all
        if($shops->isEmpty()){
            return $this->index();
        }

    return $shops;
}
```

my result is the below instead of just the record where location and food it shows all the shops filtered by location even where food isnt a match : [image]

Answer (score 0):

The `with` method that you're using does not filter in the way that you think it does. Your code actually filters the food results, telling Eloquent to retrieve all `Shop` and either no foods, or the foods with the name `fish pepper`. This is called constraining eager loads.

The method you're looking for is `whereHas` rather than `with`. This is referred to as querying a relationships existence.

```
$shops = Shop::where('city', '=', $location)
    ->with('comments.user')
    ->whereHas('foods', function($query) use($food){
        $query->where('name','=', 'fish pepper'); 
    })
    ->get();
```

This will now return only `Shop`s that have a corresponding food entry with the name `fish pepper`.

If memory serves, `whereHas` won't actually populate `foods` for you, but in this instance you wouldn't need it, as it's safe to assume that they all have `fish pepper`. If you do want to pull all foods, change `with('comments.user')` to `with(['comments.user', 'foods'])`.

Documentation for `whereHas` and other ways of achieving this can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Documentation about what you were doing with the `with` method can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

Hope that helps.